# Change default zoom on a Google Sheet?

Tags: google-sheets

I use a shared Google sheet to display apparatus issues for a fire department. This is displayed on a tv using an Asus Chromebit. Every time someone logs into the sheet it resets the zoom to 100% which does not fit on the tv. Is there a way to lock the zoom on a specific sheet to 60%?

Comment: There's no built-in way to do this. I don't know the chromebit and your setup. Could you change the actual font and size to look right on the TV and then zoom in when editing elsewhere?

Comment: This question has been bumped by Community user eight times.

Answer (score 0):

Since the Chromebit-TV combo is for viewing only, you could **Insert > New sheet** and use an [{ array expression }](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6208276) to copy values from the data sheet to the viewing sheet. It would be a formula like this:

=`{ Sheet1!A1:N }`

You can also copy formats, including conditional formatting, from the data sheet to the viewing sheet, using **Edit > Paste special > Paste format only**. Note that the formats will *not* follow changes in formatting in the data sheet, so you will have to redo the format copy from time to time if rows or columns are inserted or deleted in the data sheet.

In the viewing sheet, set font size, row heights and column widths of the data table so that it displays well on the TV, and keep that tab open in the Chromebit.

The data sheet can then be edited normally, and its values will automatically update in the viewing sheet.